# sed extract data only between time range

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with the following entries:

```
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-22_183748.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-22_184023.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-23_205331.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-23_205606.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-24_200123.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-24_200358.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-25_115839.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-25_120115.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-26_094608.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-26_094843.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-27_122523.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-09-27_122758.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-01_230024.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-01_230300.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-02_120944.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-02_121219.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-03_151414.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-03_151649.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-04_211059.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-04_211334.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-05_064049.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-05_064324.zip
```

I want to extract Files which are between today's date & 3 days back.

For today's date `2020/10/05`, 3 days back is `2020/10/02.`

The output must be:

```
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-02_120944.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-02_121219.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-03_151414.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-03_151649.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-04_211059.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-04_211334.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-05_064049.zip
```

I tried using this command to gets 3days back date

```
date --date='-3 day' '+%Y/%m/%d'
```

And then used these command to get output between date range

```
sed -n '/3day=date --date='-3 day' '+%Y/%m/%d'/,/date/p' s.txt
```

I am getting this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated address regex
```

Please Help me to fix this issue. I'll be using this in a bash script.

Comment: Can you explain why the output should end at 2020-10-05_064049 and not at 2020-10-05_064324 since this last line is also today's date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n "/$(date --date='-3 day' '+%Y-%m-%d')/,/$(date +'%y-%m-%d')/p"
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-02_120944.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-02_121219.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-03_151414.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-03_151649.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-04_211059.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-04_211334.zip
MySql-DataBase-2020-10-05_064049.zip
```

Notice, the use of double quotes at the outermost level. Also,  notice the same format of date in both boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Using a process substitution to generate the dates and feed that to grep as the patterns to search for:

```sh
grep -F -f <(for d in {0..3}; do date -d "$d days ago" "+%F"; done) file
```